# Webpack: ignore references to svg/ttf files in css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm using webpack to export a css file. I'm using file-loader for svg/ttf files but it seems to copy them to the dist folder. Is there a way I can get webpack to just ignore referneces to svg/ttf in my css and leave as is? I've tried ignore-loader but it just replaces the file paths with [Object object].

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    performance: { hints: false },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './js/react-components/src/index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/react-components/dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // all options are optional
          filename: 'output.css',
          chunkFilename: 'chunk[id].css',
          ignoreOrder: false, // Enable to remove warnings about conflicting order
        }),
      ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9-]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
              },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                resolve: {
                    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
                },
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {},
                        },
                        "css-loader"
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case

Use `esModule: false` to fix the `[Object object]` in paths.

Also put all the assets in a `/static/` folder (source is destination).

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        outputPath: '../static',
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        esModule: false
    },
},
```

EDIT: Well that created a loop with `npm run watch`
I gave up and let the files be copied put the outputPath: './'
I also had to add an exception to `CleanWebpackPlugin`, or else they

```
 plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['!*.svg']
        }), ...
```